# auto complete Extender not calling the webservice method 

Tags: asp.net

**auto complete Extender not calling the webservice method ...**

the exact problem is ., Am using AutoComplet Extender in Example project its working fine .. but the same code(aspx code as well as webservice code) am using in my live project its not calling the web service method ...

my live project is dotnet 2.0 version

i mention my code bellow steps

- aspx Code
- asmx code

<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebSDoctor.cs" Class="WebService" %>

- asmx.cs

<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebSDoctor.cs" Class="WebService" %>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebServiceGetDoctor
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebServiceGetDoctor : System.Web.Services.WebService {
public WebServiceGetDoctor () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string[] GetDoctorName(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{
    string target = contextKey;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABMSPLWINSRV2\ABMSPL;Initial Catalog=VivusHIS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa; pwd=Bgs2000new");

    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "SerchGetDoctorDetails";
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;
    p = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefixText", prefixText);
    p = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", target);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        items.SetValue(dr[target].ToString(), i);

        if (i != 10)
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    return items;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Class="WebServiceGetDoctor"` instead of `Class="WebService"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

after the line

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```